# Как происходит передача данных в сетевых моделях(OSI, TCP/IP)

Tags: сеть, сетевое-программирование

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при передаче данных по сети, используя сетевые модели, каждый уровень, начиная с верхнего занимается определенной функцией, но сами данные отправляются с физического уровня? Т.е. Допустим сетевой уровень на одной машине не может напрямую общаться с сетевым уровнем на другой.

P.S. За ранее извиняюсь за, возможно, глупый вопрос, новичок в сетях.

Comment: *но сами данные отправляются с физического уровня?* Представь, что через виртуальный свитч общаются по сети две виртуальные машины в рамках одного VMM... так там физического уровня нет - ну то есть вообще.

Comment: @Akina А виртуальный свитч не эмулирует физический уровень?

Comment: А нафига оно надо? ну придумай хотя бы одну причину...

Comment: @Akina Для стандартизации, возможно.

Comment: С точки зрения системы есть сетевая карта, которая принимает-отправляет пакеты туда-сюда, и система всего лишь передаёт сетевой карте пакеты для передачи (обычно это Ethernet). А что там в сетевой карте происходит с физическим уровнем, систему не очень интересует. Да и как уже заметили выше, физического уровня может вообще не быть. Да и в целом модель OSI не очень работает в реальном мире и нередко подвергается критике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сузить тему до tcpip, то нас, как программистов, интересуют только один-два уровня, транспортный (собсно tcp udp ip), и тот что сверху (http/s, ftp, ssh, rtmp, webrtc, и тд), ну и свой протокол который реализует логику приложения, разумеется. И тогда путь данных выглядит так

```
AppData => HTTP => SSL  => TCP/IP => .............. => TCP/IP => SSL  => HTTP => AppData
   app  => libs => libs => kernel => physical layer => kernel => libs => libs =>    app
```

Это в общем случае, когда данные идут по проводам/воздуху. Если данные идут внутри машины, например при общении через 127.0.0.1, или pipe, физический уровень не задействуется, как и в случае эмуляции сетевых устройств: общение идет между ядром и драйверами эмулятора.

Поэтому говорить что данные отправляются с физического уровня будет некорректно.

Это по сути.

А если по модели, то там да, данные отправляются с физического уровня, остальные уровни это обертки. И когда ядро отдает данные драйверу сетевого устройства, а он выпускает их по проводу, тогда они и попадают на физический уровень. Но в случае эмулятора, можно сказать что данные на физическом уровне, когда ядро отдало данные драйверу-эмулятору.

По поводу вашего вопроса могут ли общаться сетевой уровень одной машины и другой, -- они именно это и делают, сетевой уровень зашит в драверах и железе (сетевухи, свитчи и тд). Физический уровень это сигнал в проводах (частоты, амплитуды, модуляция и тд). Это тоже зашито в железе.

Например в lan и wifi протокол сетевого уровня один и тот же - ethernet. Физически lan и wifi устройства несовместимы. Однако имея на борту и wifi и lan адаптеры мы можем объединить две сети на сетевом уровне и остальные устройства в обеих сетях будут общаться на сетевом уровне, не подозревая что где-то по пути физический уровень меняется с lan на wifi и наоборот.

Если рассмотреть VPN, там вообще можно сказать что транспортный уровень основной сети является физическим для сети vpn.